# Titanium Missing Google Analytics when Starting App

Tags: android, node.js, google-analytics, titanium

I am using Titanium 3.5.1 to finish development on an app started by a colleague. The app works fine for him and runs in the Android Emulator just fine. Also another colleague installed Titanium 3.5.1 on his Mac and started the app up just fine, no changes at all.

For me on Ubuntu 14.04 with the same Titanium the app won't start in the Emulator. I keep receiving an error for missing Google Analytics plugin. I know it's not a Linux thing as the first colleague is also using Ubuntu to develop the app. So it works fine there.

I am using the most recent of NodeJS and Oracle JDK freshly installed.

```
$ node -v
v0.12.4
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
$ ti --version
4.0.1

$ ti sdk
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 4.0.1, Titanium SDK version 3.5.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

SDK Install Locations:
   /home/land/.titanium [default]

Installed SDKs:
   3.5.1.GA [selected]  /home/land/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.5.1.GA
```

This is the error I get when I try to emulate:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1722,1722] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,1723] - In ti:/module.js:280,9
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,1724] - Message: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: analytics.google
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,1724] - Source:         throw new Error("Requested module not found: " + request);
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/module.js:280: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: analytics.google
```

I know that Google Analytics Module is there:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

All of that being stated the exact same code runs for two other colleagues without a single change being made to the code. I have also run "Clean" on the project before compiling. Same result.

Comment: This sort of error is provided when the relevant architecture of the module is not found. For example, is your emulator running x86 images instead of armv7 images, and the module does not support x86 architecture. Can you confirm with the other colleagues and find their emulator type.

Comment: Hmm, this is possible as I have 32bit Ubuntu running and they are running Mac and the other I think is 64bit. I will check, what am I looking for? Is this in the creation of the emulator selecting processor type? If this is the problem is there a way around this?

Comment: try installing genymotion to simulate Android. Works much smoother. Not a solution but a recommendation

Comment: Yes, the emilator processor type. In the AVD Manager you can find the settings of the emulator. Do validate whether the processor type of your emulator and that of your colleges is same or not. If not, then you can always create a new emulator with the supported processor type and then try to deploy the application again. You can also ask them to share the AVD from their machine, and then you can copy that in your machine and then use to run and deploy the application.

Comment: Well, none of my other colleagues use Android AVDs, they all use Genymotion. Here is what my AVD looks like: http://cdn.microthosting.com/imgs/Screenshot_at_2015-06-04_09-50-36.png

The device part is missing, but it does that every time I edit it. So I tried Genymotion, but in Genymotion it doesn't give me the option of configuring processor type. In Genymotion I get the same analytics error also: http://cdn.microthosting.com/imgs/Screenshot_at_2015-06-04_10-11-33.png

I've tried both of those emulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the developers issue base on Github. It seems it was as simple as the file name for the JAR of the module. One of the letters was uppercase. And since Linux uses case-sensitive filenames Linux couldn't find it. Renaming the file in the inspector did the trick and fixed it for me:

[image]

https://github.com/Sitata/titanium-google-analytics/issues/13#issuecomment-70508249